# OpenShift 3 Tomcat Hello World Example

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, openshift

I have a couple of **Java** webapps using **Tomcat** that run on OpenShift v2.

They have to be migrated to **OpenShift 3** on or before 31st December 2017.

I have spent some time looking at **OpenShift 3** and it seems far more complex than version 2 and very, very different.

What I would like to see is a walk-through/tutorial/example of a simple webapp preferably done from the **Eclipse IDE** (I am using Oxygen).

I have searched the web unsuccessfully for one.

**Can anyone point me in the right direction...**

Comment: For a start, read https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-eclipse-jboss-tools-openshift-online-3/ Just make sure you have up to date plugin for OpenShift.

Comment: Thanks, it has been some help but...

Comment: I am 'forced' to use an image or template on the Select template dialog. 
I don't see the one used in the example: jboss-eap64-openshift:1.3
I see four jboss-webserver30-tomcat entries and a jws30-tomcat8-basic-s2i
But when I choose them they use their own source code (from a git repository).
So I cannot follow the example and hence I am stuck...
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the end I managed to create a simple tomcat web app using the oc tool. I would have preferred to use Eclipse IDE or even OpenShift 3 Online but just could not be bothered to fit them any longer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to create a simple **tomcat web app** using the **oc** tool as described in this article: [Getting Started with JBoss Web Server](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-jboss-web-server/)

I also tried to follow the process using the Web Console but it seems to have changed a lot and I was unsuccessful...